# How can I duplicate show/hide conditions of objects while duplicating collection?

Tags: collections

[image]

As you can see in the above picture, duplicating a collection did not be applied to show/hide condition but rendering condition.

If I duplicate a collection consisting of objects with very complex hierarchy, it's very hard to manage each show/hide conditions one by one.

So I want duplicate a collection including show/hide condions.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

The eye icon hides objects temporarily. To hide objects globally, use the screen icon.
You can enable it from the outliner "funnel" menu.

**Temporarily Hide objects** (Eye icon[image])
Resets when a collection is enabled, duplicated or linked to another scene

**Globally disable objects** (Screen icon [image] )
Stays on when collection is enabled, duplicated or linked

[image]

Comment: Your answer is very good but disabling in viewports affects other view layers. I want manage each view layers with different show/hide condition.